# Ошибка в map.find

Tags: c++

Всем привет, вот есть фрагмент кода, в котором идёт проверка на находимость в мапе похожего ключа, если тип нашёл то возвращает минус 1, не нашёл 1. Мб я чёт не правильно догоняю. Но функция find возвращает итератор. Вылетает в этом коде.

```
auto search = TableCarryGroup.find(CALLSIGN);
    if((*search).first == CALLSIGN){
        return 1;
    } else
        return -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Когда элемент не найден, то возвращается итератор на элемент после конца. Обращение к данным через такой итератор недопустимо (поэтому вылетает).

Правильно было бы сделать так:

```
if(TableCarryGroup.find(CALLSIGN) != TableCarryGroup.end())
    return 1;
else
    return -1;
```

Вообще, если у вас есть некий код, который ищет значение в мапе а потом использует его, то правильный паттерн:

```
auto iter = map.find(key);
if(iter != map.end())
{
    // Используем данные
}
else
{
    // Вариант когда элемент не найден. Обращяться к данным через итератор нельзя.
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна ТОЛЬКО проверка, можно использовать функцию `count()` - вернет 0, если элемента нет. Работает в `map, set`.